# JMeter & socket.io - I can see the message I want, but the socket plugin is not showing what I expect

Tags: socket.io, jmeter, jmeter-plugins

Here is the socket message I see in the browser debugger console:
[image: browser_debugger]

More illustrative, perhaps:
[image]

I call an API operation that triggers this message over a socket.

###### What I Tried

To preclude inaccuracies, I started 2 instances of JMeter.

1. REST API call.
2. Revised version of the [GitHub JMeter example of sockets.io](https://github.com/Luminis-Arnhem/jmeter-websocket-samplers/blob/master/samples/socket.io-chatserversample.jmx), in which I just call a WebSocket Sampler repeatedly on wss://events.dev.myserver.com:443/socket.io/?EIO=4&transport=websocket.

I kicked off (2).

While that was running, I kicked off (1).

###### Expected

Eventually, (1) should show me a sampler in the View Results Tree with the message in the screenshot ("42" - GAME_STARTED)

###### Actual

The only messages I see look like this:
[image: sid]

This is really all I want to do: run the appropriate sampler, a sufficient time after making the API call, to get the message.

#### Update

We succeeded in finding the message using [python-socketio](https://python-socketio.readthedocs.io/en/latest/):

```
sio.connect("https://events.dev.server.com", transports='websocket',
            headers={'Sec-WebSocket-Extensions: permessage-deflate', 'Sec-Fetch-Dest: websocket',
                     'Sec-Fetch-Mode: websocket',
                     'Cookie: ABCSESSIONDEV=NTI3MzkwNWUtMTJmNS00Y2U0LTk1NGUtMjQ2Mzk5OTYxZWE0'})
```

And here is the output:

```
Received packet MESSAGE data 2["message","{\"locationId\":110,\"name\":\"GAME_STARTED\",\"payload\":{\"id\":146724,\"boxId\":2002,\"userId\":419,\"createdAt\":\"2022-03-02T14:35:31\",\"lastModifiedAt\":\"2022-03-02T14:35:36.752\",\"completedAt\":\"2022-03-02T14:35:36.621\",\"activationMethod\":\"TAG\",\"nfcTagId\":\"xxxxxx\",\"gameCount\":1,\"app\":false}}"]
```

I would like to use the websocket plugin to do this in JMeter now.

- tried adding Cookie to WebSocket call - only sids, no messages.
- tried adding Cookie to an HTTPS request (like the above code) - 400, bad request.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at other fields of the HTTP Request, in particular [HTTP Headers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers), most probably your JMeter request is missing some essential information.

My expectation is that in order to "start the game" (whatever it means) you need to open the page in the browser, authorize somehow, follow the steps of the [protocol upgrade mechanism](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Protocol_upgrade_mechanism), etc. to wit exactly mimic what real browser does, all the request sequence which is prior to starting the game.

You might need to [correlate](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/jmeter_proxy_step_by_step.html#correlate-start) dynamic parameters, add [HTTP Header Manager](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/using-jmeters-http-header-manager/), add [HTTP Cookie Manager](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Cookie_Manager), etc.

Comment: Thank you.  I believe my main knowledge gap is in socket.io, since I am not catching the message in a Python script, either.    I'll go as far as I can with online resources and ask a socket.io question if necessary.

Comment: Using a Python script, we were able to debug and find the message.

The critical item missing was a Cookie header.     What I would really like to do is to get this all in JMeter, but this has still eluded me.  I'll post details.